# Extract rows from a matrix using a list

Tags: r, csv, matrix, rows, subset

Good morning all

I am still newish to R, and I searched most forums for an answer to my problem (I suspect I am missing out on a crucial keyword somewhere), so apologies if I duplicate a question. My problem is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17756396/r-how-to-get-many-2000-rows-from-an-r-data-frame-by-row-name/17756438#17756438), but the answer does not quite work for me.

I have a matrix with 1.7m-odd rows, and at this point 20 columns. For the purposes of this excercise I only need to extract 20 rows from this matrix, but will need to do more than a 1000 later on. I would like to be able to import a list of all the rows I would like to subset into a smaller matrix for further analysis, and keep I hitting my head against the wall.

I have created a smaller matrix with just 2 columns of interest, and set the row names to the animal ID's. The animal ID's are unique. Apologies for the clumsy coding.

```
EBV<-read.csv(file='bfile.csv', header=F, skip=1, sep=',', col.names=c("animal","anim_name","byear","anim_name_pa","anim_name_ma","sex","wwdir_ebv","wwdir_acc","wwmat_ebv","wwmat_acc","afc_ebv","afc_acc","icp_ebv","icp_acc","shd_ebv","shd_acc","scr_ebv","scr_acc","adg_ebv","adg_acc"))
head(EBV)
tail(EBV)
a<-subset(EBV, select=c(animal))
b<-subset(EBV, select=c(wwdir_ebv,wwdir_acc))
c<-as.numeric(as.character(unlist(a)))
d<-as.numeric(as.character(unlist(b)))
x<-matrix(d, nrow=1708891,ncol=2, byrow=F)
rownames(x)<-c
colnames(x)<-c("wwdir_ebv","wwdir_acc")
head(x)

Results of head(x):

*row.name* wwdir_ebv wwdir_acc
33525056   12.0321        49
33702721   13.6674        46
33791336    6.8078        63
33907452   11.0981        51
33909847    7.4192        67
34165696    8.5039        42
```

Now what I would like to do is something like this:

```
EX<-read.csv(file='braz.csv', header=F, sep=',', col.names=c("Ani"))
X<-as.numeric(as.list(unlist(EX)))
z<-subset(x, select=c('X')
```

Where the "braz.csv" file only contains a single column, for argument's sake, with animals 33701721, 33791336 and 33909847. Extracting the animals one-by-one hasn't been too much of a problem, but typing a 1000 names one-by-one will be eventually.

I don't know it it would be more effective to keep the animalID's in a column of its own though (i.e., make a matrix of 1.7m x 3 instead of 1.7m x 2) and try to subset according to the column "animalID". My biggest concern is that list that I want to import and use for subsetting.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't know why you go to all that trouble of creating matrices instead of using the data.frame returned by `read.csv`. Your use of `subset` also confuses me (becuase `select` selects columns, but apparently you want to subset by rows). Could you possibly just need `x[rownames(x) %in% unlist(EX),]`?

Comment: Hi @Roland. Thanks, that solved my problem halfway. When I checked your solution I found that while it gives me the subset I am looking for, it also sorts the row names numerically. I have another matrix that I will be using for calculations with this matrix, and I do need to keep the animal orders the same. Unless I also sort the genotypic matrix... Will go and check to see if it works.

Comment: My code should not change the row order.

Comment: Hi. Checked. The other matrix is a 76883 x 20, where the columns are the animalID's. Transposing the matrix, sorting according to animalId and retransposing it seems like a waste of effort. So I went back to the source file, sorted according to aa<-a[order(a[,1],a[,2],decreasing=F),], constructed the 2nd matrix and bobsyouruncle. But for some strange reason I now found that when using y<-x[rownames(x) %in% unlist(EX),]`, it leaves-out row 15, and swops row 19 and 20 around, so I only have a 19 x 2 matrix left. The order of the file only changes when that line is run. Any ideas?

Comment: I can only point out the importance of a [minimal reprodicible example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5963610/1412059).

Comment: Hi Roland, found the error. It was in the original dataset - animals in row 15 and row 20 of the subset were too young to have data. Thanks for all your help! Now, how do I mark your first comment as the answer?

Comment: I've copied my comment into an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why you go to all that trouble of creating matrices instead of using the data.frame returned by `read.csv`. Your use of `subset` also confuses me (because `select` selects columns, but apparently you want to subset by rows).

It appears you simply need `x[rownames(x) %in% unlist(EX),]`. Generally, you'll find that `[` is not less convenient than `subset` for subsetting, but more powerful. `subset` can also result in trouble when used inside functions. I'd advise you to study `help("[")`. `help("%in%")` might also be worth reading.